# Getting a substring AFTER the last occurrence of a character in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a string in an XML file that looks similar to this:

> M:Namespace.Class.Method(Something a, Something b)

The number of period (.) characters is abritrary, meaning it can be only 2 as in this example, but can be more.

I would like to use XSLT to get a substring of this string from the last '.' character, so that i will only be left with:

> Method(Something a, Something b)

I could not achieve this using the standard substring/substring-after functions.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527/xslt-reverse-find-in-a-string ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0 you will need to use a recursive template**, like this:

```
  <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
          <xsl:with-param name="string"
            select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of 
                  select="$string" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

and invoke it like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
  <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'M:Namespace.Class.Method(Something a, Something b)'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'.'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

**In XSLT 2.0, you can use the [tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) function** and simply select the last item in the sequence:

```
tokenize('M:Namespace.Class.Method(Something a, Something b)','\.')[last()]
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i know which version of XSLT am i using? I am invoking all of this from C# code (using the XslCompiledTransform class).

Comment: Unfortunately .NET does not support XSLT 2.0 natively. Unless you have Saxon.net, XQSharp, or other 2.0 engines you will need to use a 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a more efficient solution O(N) vs. O(N^2) for the accepted answer**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="skipAfterDots">
  <xsl:param name="pTotalString" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pTotalLength" select="string-length(.)"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPosition" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pLastFound" select="-1"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pPosition > $pTotalLength">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($pTotalString, $pLastFound + 1)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vIsDot" select=
       "substring($pTotalString, $pPosition, 1) = '.'"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="skipAfterDots">
        <xsl:with-param name="pTotalString" select="$pTotalString"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pTotalLength" select="$pTotalLength"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pLastFound" select=
        "$pLastFound * not($vIsDot) + $pPosition * $vIsDot"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pPosition" select="$pPosition+1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>M:Namespace.Class.Method(Something a, Something b)</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Method(Something a, Something b)
```

**Explanation**:

**This solution doesn't contain any call to the `substring-after()` function**. Instead, at each step only the one character of the string is compared for equality with the dot character. Because there are at most N characters, this is O(N) -- linear complexity.

**On the contrary, the accepted answer calls the `substring-after()` function on every step**. In the worst case there could be N dots and thus this would be O(N^N) -- quadratic complexity.

**Note**: We make the reasonable assumption that in both solutions locating the k-th character of a string is O(1).

Comment: Old comment, but I feel a need to comment: the accepted solution is also O(n). Each call to (a sane implementation of) `contains()` will look through leading characters until it finds a dot. After it finds a dot, every character it has looked at so far is discarded. Therefore, it will look at each character at most once.

Comment: @nemetroid: I am referring to `<xsl:with-param name="string"       select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)"/>`. If there are `m` dots in the string and the string length is `n`, then this algorithm is `O(m*n)`

Comment: Right, you are correct. I did not consider that `substring-after` will have to look through the entire (remaining) string.

Comment: @nemetroid: My explanation was misleading (mentioned `contains()` instead of `substring-after()`). Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do know that you have exactly **two** dots in your strings then you can try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($str, '.'), '.')" />
```

Comment: This will not work if i have an arbitrary number of . in my string.. For example: Component.Something.Else.Class.Method( ... )