# Substring Text Before last '&amp;' in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

Below is Text -
111 Somerton Ave&#xa;Kenmore, NY 14217&#xa;United States of America

I want to print the substring of text before the last '&'.

Desired Text o/p -
111 Somerton Ave&#xa;Kenmore, NY 14217

Note: Basically I want to remove the Country name from the text using XSLT

Comment: Please edit your post and add a minimal reproducible example, i.e. XML/XSLT.

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078779/getting-a-substring-after-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-xslt?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If - as it seems = there will be always exactly 2 line breaks in the given input, you could do this without recursion, just by using `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`. -- Note also that recursion would only be needed in XSLT 1.0.